# Issue with Include in Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have Employee, Address and Organization classes. below are the details

```
public partial class Employees
{
    public Employees()
    {
        AddressDetails = new HashSet<AddressDetails>();
        OrganizationDetails = new HashSet<OrganizationDetails>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AddressDetails> AddressDetails { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrganizationDetails> OrganizationDetails { get; set; }
}

public partial class AddressDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public Employees Employee { get; set; }
}

public partial class OrganizationDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public Employees Employee { get; set; }
}
```

I have used fully defined relationship, you can see Employee has collections of both AddressDetails and OrganizationDetails as navigation properties. And each of them have EmployeeId and Employee in the same way.

My problem is, when i try to fetch Employee details using Include(), both AddressDetails and OrganizationDetails are loaded that's fine, but when i checked both the collections each entity has again loaded Employee information and so on.

for example: if i check AddressDetails collection which is loaded, Address object has information of Employee and again that Employee has collections of both AddressDetails and OrganizationDetails.

Please help me how can i avoid this. I don't want to remove Employee object property from AddressDetails and OrganizationDetails. is there anyway to make it work with Include().

here is the query i'm using to load these navigation properties.

List employees = _context.Employees.Include(emp => emp.AddressDetails).Include(emp => emp.OrganizationDetails).ToList();

Comment: There is no error here. In fact the `Employees` object in your `AddressDetails` object is the exact same object you started from when using `Include()`. It is just a cyclic reference.

Comment: Thanks @progman, I cannot pass the same data from web API. it is unable to serialize it. is there anyway to ignore those cyclic references.

Comment: Yes, don't send database entities over the web API. Instead create new classes with the layout you want/need for your web API and convert between them (maybe with automapper).